# What is the $n$ in the formula in Solid Mechanics?

Tags: continuum-mechanics, stress-strain, solid-mechanics, structural-beam

The formula is about the critical force for the elastic beam that is supported by its joints:

$$  P_{cr} ~=~ n^2  \pi^2  \frac{EI}{ L^2}      $$

It should be based on the book Parnes - Solid Mechanics in Engineering, but I cannot find any explanation for $n$.

**What does the $n$ describe in the formula?**

Comment: Well, where did you find it to begin with?

Comment: This is all pieces of information that was given to me.

Comment: Well, I take it your formula did not arrive by fax from Heaven. Who "gave you" that information? Reference your sources!

Comment: Exercise given by a old student in my course. Original source probably Parnes book or some other book. I do not know.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

"different values of n represent different modes of buckling" (http://emweb.unl.edu/NEGAHBAN/Em325/21-Buckling%20of%20columns/Buckling%20of%20columns.htm )

Comment: Shockingly, this link hasn't rotted away yet. It would be nice if this answer were edited to stand alone anyway.

Comment: @rob : I would say the answer does stand alone: it explains that $n$ characterizes the buckling mode.